# RoR Simple Friendly Slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm currently using Friendly_ID to create friendly slugs of the form "/post/friendly-name".

e.g., routes.rb reads:

```
get '/posts/:id', to: 'posts#show'
```

HOWEVER, I don't want the "/post" element: the public url should simply be "/friendly-name".

For the life of me, I can't find a clean way to do this. The closest potential solution seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371487/match-multiple-models-in-single-rails-route-with-friendly-id) which adds a lot of complication to the model for a seemingly simple feature.

Comment: so for my understanding u wanna `URL/friendly-name` of the post, instead of `/URL/posts/friend-name` ?

Comment: Precisely that ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting:

```
get '/:id', to: 'posts#show'
```

at the *end* of `routes.rb`?

Since routes are matched from top to bottom, this route will only be reached if no other previous matching route was found.

If you put it earlier than at the end, then all sorts of mayhem may occur.

Comment: Thanks jvillian, this solves it!

Out of curiosity - is this the optimal way to structure, or does it leave any security holes?